# Location Services in iOS 8: Background Modes

Tags: ios, ios8, core-location

There is a Background mode called Location Updates.

If I include the CoreLocation framework, and in my info.plist include the key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and the value being a String with whatever I need to use it for, do I need to tick the background mode for Location Updates? Can I just use it upon authorization? I've tried looking up iOS 8 guides for Core Location as I've never used it before, but nothing touches on this. I don't know what it is used for if you don't have to tick it for getting location in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get authorized for the AlwaysUsage, you can get location whenever your code is running. But it won't run on background unless you have activated an appropriate mode for that.

[Apple's Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) describes the philosophy of background modes pretty well.

Comment: Oh, I see. So to have AlwaysUsage working as one would expect, the Background mode needs to be ticked.